# Azure WebApp not accessable: The service is unavailable

Tags: azure, service, azure-web-app-service

I have an azure webapp which is since yesterday no longer accessable. It is a java based war file deployed into a java-8 tomcat-9 environment. The web-app service says it is running, but it is not. I cant either get my web page nor can I connect to the ssh portal. When I access the logfiles via (s)ftp I see that there are no new logs even when I restart the webapp. So what can I do next to at least see why the tomcat or the container is not even trying to start?

Error Message is a "The service is unavailable." 5xx code both for ssh and the webservice itself.

using the cloud shell I get the following:

```
user@Azure:~$ az webapp show --ids <MYID>|grep state
"state": "Running"
user@Azure:~$ az webapp create-remote-connection --ids <MYID>
Failed to connect to 'https://<MYHOST>.azurewebsites.net/AppServiceTunnel/Tunnel.ashx?GetStatus' with status code '503' and reason 'Site Unavailable'
user@Azure:~$ az webapp ssh --ids <MYID>
This command is in preview. It may be changed/removed in a future release.
Failed to connect to 'https://<MYHOST>.scm.azurewebsites.net/AppServiceTunnel/Tunnel.ashx?GetStatus' with status code '503' and reason 'Site Unavailable'
```

Regards
Lukas

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the error (503) may be caused by the application level issues, requests taking a long time; application using high memory/CPU or application crashing due to an exception.
Apologies for the delay! If the issue is still not sorted out. I understand you had noticed this issue on Dec 16. Is this issue confined to any specific WebApp in any specific App Service plan/region or does this happen across several WebApps/regions in your subscription?

1.You may Scale Up the App Service Plan to a higher plan and see if that makes any difference.

2.You could review the Service Health and Resource Health notifications.

The ‘[Service Health](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/service-health/service-health-overview)’ - Service issues view shows any ongoing problems in Azure services that are impacting your resources. You can understand when the issue began, and what services and regions are impacted. You can also read the most recent update to understand what Azure is doing to resolve the issue.

[Resource health](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/service-health/resource-health-overview) helps you diagnose and get support when an Azure issue impacts your resources. It informs you about the current and past health of your resources and helps you mitigate issues. Resource health provides technical support when you need help with Azure service issues.

3.Leverage App Service diagnostics to fetch more details on the error. 
To access App Service diagnostics, navigate to your App Service app in the Azure portal. In the left navigation, click on Diagnose and solve problems.

[image]

Kindly let us know how the above goes for further investigation.